# Detect when a notification appears (from another application) to change my layout

Tags: ios, uikit

Do I want to know if it's possible to detect when a notification from another application is over my app? For example, when the user receives an SMS or Messenger message. Detect the fact that a notification is present on the screen. I don't want the content of the message.

It's an example, It can be a notification for whatever. Because, when a notification is visible, my player's lost because a part of the UI is under the notification. So, if I know when a notification is visible I can change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to handle notifications from other apps. It would be a huge privacy violation.

Comment: I don't want to know the content of the message. I just want to know when a notification is visible over my app. The message is an example, It can be a notification for whatever. Because, when a notification is visible, my player's lost because a part of the UI is under the notification. So, if I know when a notification is visible I can change the de layout.

Comment: I just want to detect, like we can detect when the keyboard is open or close.

Comment: The answer is still No. You cannot detect it. The only thing you can try is to subscribe to `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`. But keep in mind, that if the banner is shown above your application, it is still active. So in your case it will only help in case of alerts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!